How can I implement an MWPM decoder for heralded errors(biased error) in stim?
I am trying to use the ``HERALDED_PAULI_CHANNEL_1'' in stim to implement biased errors. However, if I use this feature, I understand that I won't be able to use stim's pymatching decoder'', so I need to find a separate decoder. Do you have any suggestions or tips on how to implement the MWPM decoder in a way that is compatible with stim?

The simplest thing to do would be to modify pymatching to look for marked detectors (e.g. detectors you gave special coordinate data) and treat them differently, such as noting down the edges associated with them and lowering the weights of those edges before running the matching.
This is a non-trivial programming task, there will be a lot of details to getting it to work, but conceptually it's not too complicated.

Your response was very helpful. Thank you!
